# How to workaround NAs in subscripted assignments

Tags: r

I have some data with a representative subpart here

```
id     visitdate   ecgday
5130   1999-09-22  1999-09-22
6618   NA          1999-12-01 
10728  2000-06-27  2000-06-27
968    1999-04-19  1999-04-19
5729   1999-09-23  NA
1946   NA          NA
15070  1999-11-09  NA
```

What I want is to create a novel variable visitday which is equal to ecgday, unless ecgday is NA. In that case it should be `visitday -> visitdate` unless both visitdate and ecgday are NA, where visitday should be NA.

I have tried

```
int99$visitday <- int99$visitdate    
int99$visitday[!is.na(int99$ecgday) & int99$ecgday > int99$visitdate]   
     <-int99$ecgday[!is.na(int99$ecgday) & int99$ecgday > int99$visitdate]
```

but it gave the error:

> Error in [.data.frame(int99, , c("id", "visitday", "visitdate",  : 
>         undefined columns selected

which I understand. Any workaround to get the desired result?

Comment: In your example data, there is no TRUE cases and also you need `!is.na(visitdate)`.  Also, based on your code, I am not getting any error with 'visitdate' and 'ecgday' as `Date` class

Comment: You are absolutely right. I forgot an important line into the R source (edited in now).

Comment: @JørgenK.Kanters that should work but `ifelse` is a little funny  with dates I would add it first as a character, and then transform it to date to go seemlessly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this Should do it:

First if ecday is NA it will be visitday, if not it will be ecgday

```
int99$visitday <- felse(is.na(int99$ecgday), int99$visitdate , int99$ecgday)
```

for cases when both have NAs, you can add a next ifelse:

```
int99$visitday <- ifelse(is.na(int99$visitdate), int99$ecgday , int99$visitdate)
```

Comment: nice. simple and straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Derek Corcoran

That worked except for a very small thing that visitday ended up being numeric despite both ecgday and visitdate being Date.

That was easy fixed by adding a line

```
int99$visitday <- ifelse(is.na(int99$ecgday), int99$visitdate , int99$ecgday)
int99$visitday <- ifelse(is.na(int99$visitdate), int99$ecgday , int99$visitdate)
int99$visitday <- as.Date(int99$visitday, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0):

In my view the best way to deal with such NA comparison it to change dates to numeric and all NAs to 0. Though quite possibly I did not understand the question correctly, in case you want to set the new variable to the higher of the visitdate and ecgday, you can try this. 
Or it can be adapted to any other requirement

```
int99<- read.table(header = T, colClasses = c("numeric", "Date","Date"),
text="id visitdate ecgday
5130 1999-09-22 1999-09-22
6618 NA 1999-12-01 
10728 2000-06-27 2000-06-27
968 1999-04-19 1999-04-19
5729 1999-09-23 NA
1946 NA NA
15070 1999-11-09 NA" )

dt<- apply(int99[,2:3], 2 , zoo::as.Date)
dt  
dt[is.na(dt)]<- 0
dt  
mx<- apply(dt,1,max)

mx[mx==0]<- NA

int99$visitday<- zoo::as.Date(mx)

int99
```